# XPATH partial match tr id with Python, Selenium,

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

could I please have the correct XPATH to extract the tr id="review_" elements as well?
I managed to get the  elements but lucking out on the IDs as they are a partial match

```
<table class="admin">
<thead>"snip"</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="review_984669" class="">
    <td>weird_wild_and_wonderful_mammals</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="book_review[approved]" id="approved" value="1" class="attribute_toggle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="book_review[rejected]" id="rejected" value="1" class="attribute_toggle"></td>
    <td>February 27, 2019 03:56</td>
    <td><a href="/admin/new_book_reviews/984669?page=2">Show</a></td>
    <td>
        <span class="rest-in-place" data-attribute="review" data-object="book_review" data-url="/admin/new_book_reviews/984669">
bad
        </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="review_984670" class="striped">
```

I used Selenium with Chrome to extract the only table on the page.

```
Table_Selenium_Elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="admin"]/table')
```

Then I was using the below to get the data from each row.

```
for Pri_Key, element in enumerate(Table_Selenium_Elements.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr')):
# Create an empty secondary dict for each new Pri Key
    sec = {}
    # Secondary dictionary needs a Key. Keys are items in column_headers list
    for counter, Sec_Key in enumerate(column_headers):
        # Secondary dictionary needs Values for each key.
        # Values are individual items in each sub-list of column_data list
        # Slice the sub list with the counter to get each item
        sec[Sec_Key] = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')[counter]
    pri[Pri_Key] = sec
```

This is only showing the data in each  ie
"weird_wild_and_wonderful_mammals", "1"

BUT I actually need the tr id=review_xxx as well. I don't know how to do this.
The id number changes so maybe a xpath 'contains' expression OR a xpath 'begins_with' expression.

Since I'm a noob I think I have captured the review_ID but I am not extracting correctly via my for loop.

Could someone please show me the correct XPATH to extract the parent tr, and child tds.
...and then I will tweak my for loop.
Thankyou
Sam

Comment: Can you share full html and your code or share url?

Comment: @DaftVader Exactly which elements are you referring to as `tr id="review_" elements`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your html with below selectors example you can get all rows:

```
admin_table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".admin tbody > tr")
admin_table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".admin tr[id^='review_']")
admin_table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='admin']//tr[starts-with(@id,'review_')]")
```

To get `id` attribute you can use `element.get_attribute("id")` method.

Here example how you can scrape data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

admin_table_rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".admin tr[id^='review_']")))

for row in admin_table_rows:
    row_id = row.get_attribute("id").replace("review_", "")
    label = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(1)")
    num = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(2)")
    date = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(3)")
    href = row.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Sers, you are the best. This just works. Thank you very much :)
You identified my problem, presented your answer in a really clear way and gave me some alternatives - some reading suggests that xpath is fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking for an xPath to locate the table element itself?

In your example you have an xPath looking for the table you have

```
[@id="admin"]
```

'admin' is the class, not the id.  Does it work if you simply switch this to

```
Table_Selenium_Elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="admin"]/table')
```

Comment: No, I have the table, I was not getting the correct data out of it though. I think I was only getting the td information, not the tr and the td information.
@Sers answer did not modify my table extraction code. Instead, Sers showed better ways to get data out of the table with:
`row.get_attribute("id").replace("review_", "" `**<--this is what I was really needing**
`row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(1)")`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('striped')
```

or

```
# If it is the last row in the table.
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody tr')[-1]
```

or

```
# If it is surely the 2nd row in the table.
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody tr')[1]
```

Comment: Sorry but the rows have different classes as per my orignal code
<tr id="review_984669" class="">
<tr id="review_984670" class="striped">